# The changes I made doesn't take effect on vue js laravel

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

I have a file named `Notification.vue` inside components folder.

From my **app.js**, I imported the notification.vue as below:

```
Vue.component('notification', require('./components/Notification.vue'));
```

The above code is working fine.

However, when I made changes on `Notification.vue`, the expected output is not executing. Hence, I tried the following Attempts:

1. I cleared my cache
2. I executed `php artisan cache:clear`
3. I deleted the file `Notification.vue` - (I expected an error on my console but none.)

But still, the output is still the same. No changes is seen on my site.

Does anybody know what's going on here and how to fix this? thanks

Comment: run the following command `npm run watch` from the cmd to compile vuejs, also include the js file in your view

Comment: I tried that but still no effect. I even tried npm install forever-monitor still error

Comment: How do you call your notification component? you need to call it from the view like this <notification></notification> before it can work, will upload example soon.

Comment: Yeah. I have that already.

Comment: what about the JavaScript file you compiled (app.js) using `npm run watch` do you include if in your `app.blade.php` footer? if yes, check your browser console to see if there's any error and if vuejs is enable

Comment: Please post your component, Vue instance and HTML where you are calling the component. You will get much better answers if you have complete code examples

Comment: It doesn't matter if I am going to put my code because even if I put the file or delete the file, no changes occurs on the website. This is what happened, I saw on `public/js/app.js` the codes I added on notification.vue. It seems that the browser is reading the codes from the app.js and not on the notification.vue, hence, I need to refresh the app.js so that it will copy the new codes from notifcation.vue. But, now, I don't know how to reset the app.js

Comment: I had the same problem, just clear your browser cache :)